# I don't know what's wrong with my python code

Tags: python

instructions

1. Below your existing code, define a function called rental_car_cost with an argument called days.
   Calculate the cost of renting the car:
   Every day you rent the car costs $40.
   if you rent the car for 7 or more days, you get $50 off your total.
   Alternatively (elif), if you rent the car for 3 or more days, you get $20 off your total.
   You cannot get both of the above discounts.
   Return that cost.

Just like in the example above, this check becomes simpler if you make the 7-day check an if statement and the 3-day check an elif statement.

#the code

```
def rentalcarcost(days):
  cost = 40 * days
  if days >= 7:
    return cost - 50
  elif days >= 3:
    return cost - 20
  else :
    return cost
```

Comment: Your problem is that your code should be on multiple lines if you want to write it on a single line just remove ":" please note that in the case multiple line code you should write spaces inside code sections like 3 spaces deeper

Comment: YOu didn't mention what the problem is...

Comment: @CyanogenCX I hope you realize that your edit may have invalidated the question. In this case, it doesn't seem to have, but the OP didn't give an error message. In the future, _do not_ edit code to make it look prettier unless you're absolutely _certain_ that it doesn't change the meaning of the code in any way, shape, or form.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct code, if your code isn't working for you even after the indentation is fixed:

```
def car_cost(days):
    cost = 40*days
    if days>=7:
        cost = cost-50
    elif days>=3:
        cost = cost-20
    return cost
```

INDENTATION MATTERS IN PYTHON!

Here is your code indented properly.

```
def rentalcarcost(days):
    cost = 40 * days
    if days >= 7:
        return cost - 50
    elif days >= 3:
        return cost - 20
    else:
        return cost
```